# Export .html from SAS Visual Analytics

Tags: html, graph, sas, sas-visual-analytics

How can I export graphs created in Visual Analytics as .html? 
From the export menus only .png and .pdf is available, but I need the ability to do drill downs directly from the web browser in the same manner as files exported from Enterprise Guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible as of now. The closest solution is to create a reporting and present it via the report viewer. VA works on live data. The reports are not pre-rendered/aggregated. Therefore they can not be exported.

Address the topic with SAS. You are certainly not the only one that needs this feature. If enough customers demand it, they will implement it.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I'll definitely address this with SAS and if they have any alternative solutions I'll forward it here.